# how to allocate memory for 3D array using calloc in c++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, dynamic-allocation, calloc

I want to allocate memory for 3d array in c++ one by one like..

```
typedef struct {
int id;int use;
}slotstruct;
slotstruct slot1[3][100][1500];  // This should be 3d array
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
  for(j=0;j<100;j++){
     for(k=0;k<1500;k++){
         slot1[i][j][k] = (slotstruct *)calloc(1,sizeof(slotstruct));
      }
   }
}
```

i  have used this code but i am getting segmentation fault..

Comment: You have wrong idea about arrays, nevertheless, this code won't give you segmentation fault. This code won't compile at all, even when wrapped in a function with all required declarations and includes. Post your real code.

Comment: I'm afraid that what you call C++ it's actually C. A couple of standards old, too.

Comment: @Bob__ this is just small part of my project.. my whole project is in c++ so by this small code you won't be able to differentiate

Comment: @michalsrb in my project there are 3 beams for each beam there is 100 channels and in each channel there are 1500 slots so in main fun i will call this method to allocate memory..

Comment: Have you considered to use a class with a 1D std::vector and a custom accessor?

Comment: @Bob__  sorry but i am not able to understand what you are trying to ask me.

Comment: I mean something like [this](https://ideone.com/wwsIlq).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the total amount of memory needed first then allocate memory first for main array and the sub arrays as below. It won't cause segmentation fault.
Even you can check the addresses also they are **contiguous**.
Try below code it works fine for me:

```
typedef struct
{
int id;
int use;
}slotstruct;

main()
{
        int i,j,k;
        char row=2 ,col =3, var=3;
        //char **a=(char**)malloc(col*sizeof(char*));
        slotstruct*** a =(slotstruct***)calloc(col,sizeof(slotstruct*));

        for(i=0;i<col;i++)
                a[i]=(slotstruct**)calloc(row,sizeof(slotstruct*));

        for(i=0;i<col;i++)
                for(j=0;j<row;j++)
                        a[i][j]=(slotstruct*)calloc(var,sizeof(slotstruct*));


        int cnt=0;
        for( i=0;i<col;i++)
                for( j=0;j<row;j++)
                {
                        for(k=0;k<var;k++)
                                a[i][j][k].id=cnt++;
                }

        for(i=0;i<col;i++)
                for(j=0;j<row;j++)
                {
                        for(k=0;k<var;k++)
                                printf("%d ",a[i][j][k].id);
                                printf("%u ",&a[i][j][k]);
                        printf("\n");
                }
}
```

Comment: The addresses are not guaranteed to be contigous if allocated this way. You should also remember to free the memory before exiting.

Comment: Yeah I need to free the memory as well.

Comment: @Stubborn why you have used sizeof(int*) i am not able to understand.!

Comment: @nim that was by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Write

```
slotstruct ( *slot1 )[100][1500];

slot1 = calloc( 1, 3 * sizeof( *slot1 ) );
```

Or try something like the following

```
slotstruct ***slot1;

slot1 = malloc( 3 * sizeof( slotstruct ** ) );

for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
{ 
    slot1[i] = malloc( 100 * sizeof( slotstruct * ) );
    for ( int j = 0; j < 100; j++ )
    {
        slot1[i][j] = calloc( 1, 1500 * sizeof( slotstruct ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not as per my requirement.. when i print addresses using thid code snippet i am getting addresses like.                                         16135008 , 161350016 , 161350024 , 16137024 while i need like 5008,50016,50024,50032,50040,50048

Comment: @nlm you have tried the second snippet, what about the first?

Comment: i want to allocate dynamically.. i think first method would be static way of allocation.

Comment: @nlm The both shown methods allocate memory dynamically.

Comment: in first one it is dynamic but not one by one.. three conditions should be satisfied one by one allocation + dynamically + continuous..

Comment: @nlm Use the second one. What is the problem?

Comment: when i am using first one in my code it is giving err like calloc:invalid conversion from (void*) to slotstruct(*)[100][1500].. i think it is c++/c err.. because same code executed with c compiler it does not give err but when i am using c++ compiler it gives err.. and my project is in c++ so i have to use c++ compiler..

Comment: @nlm  You are compiling the program as a C++ program instead of a C ptogram. In C this statement is valid. In C++ you have to use operator new instead of calloc or malloc.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow but by using new it will not allocate memory continuous.. my primary requirement is continuous memory allocation..

Comment: @nlm You adked about calloc. I showed how one extent can be allocated using callo. You can also use the new operator in C++ to allocate one extent.

Answer (score -1):

You've already allocated memory when you wrote

```
slotstruct slot1[3][100][1500]
```

Did you mean to write following?

```
slotstruct ***slot1
```

Comment: yes.. but i don't know how to allocate using ***slot1. it should be contiguous and one by one.